# How to pass arguments to Unix-like commands (via MinGW) in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, mingw

I'm using MinGW on my Windows machine, and when I use it with the `command-prompt`, things work as expected:

- `ls` lists the visible files
- `ls -a` lists all files, etc

But, when I fire up Powershell, it keeps throwing errors when I pass arguments to my commands as so:

```
D:\>ls -al .

Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'al'.
At line:1 char:4
+ ls -al .
+    ~~~
  + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

What can I do to use all my MinGW/msys commands properly via Powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ls` is an alias in Powershell for the `get-childitem` command. If you want to run an external command called `ls` you will need to force Powershell to ignore its own `ls` command.

You could try running `ls.exe`, or specify the path to the MinGW command, or undefine the Powershell alias. Or learn to use the options for Powershell's own `ls` command instead.

The nearest Powershell equivalent to `ls -al` would be `ls -Force` This will display all hidden and system files and Powershell's default output for `ls` looks somewhat like the `ls -l` format anyway.

You can check which command will be run using Powershell's `get-command` which does a similar job to `which` (or use `gcm` as shorthand for less typing:

```
PS C:\Users\IEUser> get-command ls.exe

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ls.exe                                             0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin\ls.exe


PS C:\Users\IEUser> get-command ls

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem

PS C:\Users\IEUser> gcm ls

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem


PS C:\Users\IEUser> gcm ls.exe

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ls.exe                                             0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\bin\ls.exe
```

and if you don't want to learn a new command:

```
PS C:\Users\IEUser> set-alias which gcm
PS C:\Users\IEUser> which ls

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
```

Comment: Thanks! I admit, I had never though of this possibility :)
Referring to `ls.exe -al` does work indeed.

Comment: Also, to check whether the `ls` you are using is actually powershell's alias or mingw's executable, you can run `which ls`. If it outputs something like `/usr/bin/ls` then it's mingw. if it throws error like `/usr/bin/which: no ls in ...`, then it's powershell's alias

Comment: @kumar_harsh, not quite true because `which` might find an existing `ls.exe` but powershell will use its own alias in preference. Use `get-command` or `gcm` to see what Powershell is actually going to run (I've updated my answer to include an example).

Comment: yes, you're right. `ls` and `ls.exe` might be different - in fact, this happens to me already with `find`.